# Is HP Deskjet advantage 3545 all-in-one printer compatable with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS?

Tags: 14.04

Is HP Deskjet advantage 3545 all-in-one printer compatable with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS  and above version of ubuntu ?

Comment: I am using a 3520 with 12.04, but had to download the newest hplip from HP, not the version in the repository which was too old. Not sure if the version in 14.04 is new enough or not? http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html and: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html

Answer (score 3):

It is supported by hplib driver set. You can download and install it with these commands:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/hplip/hplip-3.13.8.run
```

```
sh hplip-3.13.8.run
```

Comment: sourceforge site: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.13.8/

ubuntu docs: ( note 14.04 needs gui support, instructions here )
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne

Answer (score 0):

The printer is not [officially supported](https://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/HP).

You can install your printer via [HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_2540_series.html)

```
sudo apt-get install hplip
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Connect your printer to the PC and turn the printer on. Open a terminal and start the installation with

```
hp-setup
```

To use the GUI, start the command

```
hp-toolbox
```

or start *HP Toolbox* in your Dash.

[image]